# Unable to connect my computer through its own IP(192.168.1.102)

Tags: localhost

I'm trying to connect my iPhone to my localhost. My computer's LAN IP is 192.168.1.102. And in My iPhone, I cannot connect to 192.168.1.102:3000(the local Rails Server).

Then, I try to debug by myself. In my computer, I type 192.168.1.102:3000. And **I cannot connect to my PC itself**. Is this the problem? (Certainly, I can visit from localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000)

Comment: is your firewall deactivated or does it accept incoming requests?

Comment: @DanielRuf  I'm on win7. And I have disabled or open the port(both in and out for TCP) when doing these things. It didn't work.

Comment: and your router/modem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I run `rails s -b 192.168.1.102`(my local ip). And the problem solved